# On deploy trigger a webhook in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure App Service set up to deploy from a local git branch. (per instruction from [this article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AzureDevOpsContinuousBuildDeployTestWithASPNETCore22PreviewInOneHour.aspx)). I would like these deployments to trigger another webhook  I have set up that posts deploy logs to slack, but I don't see any way to configure a push option in the Azure UI.

Any tips or ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) to do that.

Here's an Official Azure Documentation [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) that will help you to **work with HTTP triggers and output bindings in Azure Functions**

---

If this solves your problem, do not forget to click on *Mark as Answer*